# Android studio media player dont start streaming with icecast 2 url why?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, icecast

**I have a server with icecast2 that streams music.

I tried to make a simple android player that is able to listen to music streaming.

It doesn't work with my url. While if I use other url like the ones found on https://www.soundhelix.com/audio-examples everything works fine.

I think the problem lies with this issue of the documentation "Note: If you're passing a URL to stream an online media file, the file must be capable of progressive download."

I thought Icecast2 did this but obviously not.

Do you know how I can solve the problem? is it possible to set icecast to make it progressive download?**

```
2021-12-14 20:00:39.754 15925-15955/com.radio.radiopiombino E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0xb8a379c0)
2021-12-14 20:00:39.754 15925-15955/com.radio.radiopiombino E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2021-12-14 20:00:39.757 15925-15925/com.radio.radiopiombino E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2021-12-14 20:01:03.330 15925-15925/com.radio.radiopiombino E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0xb8a379c0)
2021-12-14 20:01:03.330 15925-15925/com.radio.radiopiombino E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2021-12-14 20:01:03.330 15925-15925/com.radio.radiopiombino E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2021-12-14 20:01:03.863 15925-15925/com.radio.radiopiombino E/MediaPlayerNative: prepareAsync called in state 0, mPlayer(0xb8a379c0)
```

Player Code

````
    public void run() {


            String url = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3";

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                    new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                            .build()
            );

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Toast.makeText(this, url, 10).show();
            mediaPlayer.start();

            play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){

                    mediaPlayer.stop(); //pause()
                }else{
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
            });
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Your Icecast stream *is* a progressive download by nature.  What's the URL?

Comment: this http://radiopiombinolive.m2a.club:8000/rapi.mp3

Comment: i add the player code on question

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see anything wrong with your stream, sorry.

Comment: wrong code player ?